# jQuery mobile pagecontainer change not working on swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working with jqm 1.4.5.

I want pages to change when user to swipes left and right.
So I created this code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", ".my-page", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", ".my-page", function( e ) {
        var prevLink = <some url>;
        var nextLink = <some url>;
        if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
            $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", nextLink, { reloadPage: true});
        } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
            $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prevLink, { reloadPage: true});
        }
    }
});
```

I get this error on the console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

On line with this code:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", nextLink, { reloadPage: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a long time and search i fount the answer.
Just change the:

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", nextLink, { reloadPage: true});
```

To:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", nextLink);
```

Works like a charm :-)